# Ignore UserWarning from openpyxl using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have tons of .xlsm files that I have to load. Each Excel file has 6 sheets. Because of that, I'm opening each Excel file like this, using pandas:

```
for excel_file in files_list:
    with pd.ExcelFile(excel_file, engine = "openpyxl") as f:
        df1 = pd.read_excel(f, "Sheet1")
        df2 = pd.read_excel(f, "Sheet2")
        df3 = pd.read_excel(f, "Sheet3")
        ...
```

After each iteration I am passing the df to other function and do some stuff with it. I am using `pd.ExcelFile` to load the file into memory just once and then separate it on DataFrames.

However, when doing this, I am getting the following warning:

```
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py:300: UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed
warn(msg)
```

No matter the warning, the information is loaded correctly from the Excel file and no data is missing. It takes about 0.8s to load each Excel file and all of its sheets into df. If I use the default engine on pandas to load each Excel file, the warning goes away, but the time it takes for each file goes up to 5 or even 6 seconds.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53965596/python-3-openpyxl-userwarning-data-validation-extension-not-supported) post, but there wasn't an answer on how to remove the warning, which is what I need, as everything's working correctly.

How can I disable said UserWarning?

Comment: The warning isn't about data but about some extensions to the specification. It's a courtesy.

Comment: Kind of feel like the better solution would be to update pandas here instead of suppressing the warning...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this using `warnings` core module:

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=UserWarning, module='openpyxl')
```

You can also specify the particular module you'd like to silence warnings for by adding an argument `module="openpyxl"`.

Comment: Minor typo in the answer, it's actually `warnings.simplefilter`. And `simplefilter` doesn't support the `module` parameter. Instead use `warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=UserWarning, module='openpyxl')`.

Answer (score 4):

See [What causes "UserWarning: Discarded range with reserved name" - openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169149/what-causes-userwarning-discarded-range-with-reserved-name-openpyxl)  -- different warning, same solution - so you put the warnings back to default after you open the book, since there may be other warnings that you do want to see.

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
wb = load_workbook(path)
warnings.simplefilter("default")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore this warning specifically, and do it in a given context only, you can combine `catch_warnings` and `filterwarnings` with the `message` argument. E.g:

```py
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed")
    data = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None)
```

Note: `sheet_name=None` will read all the Excel sheets in one go too.